# how to find indices of a 2d numpy array occuring in another 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2d numpy arrays and want to find where one array is occuring in another one:

```
big_array = np.array([[1., 2., 1.2], [5., 3., 0.12], [-1., 14., 0.], [-9., 0., 13.]])
small_array= np.array([[5., 3., 0.12], [-9., 0., 13.]])
```

Then I want to get the indices of the rows of `big_array` which are the same as any rows of `small_array`. I want to do somthing like `np.in1d` for 2d arrays. I mean I want to have:

```
result= [1, 3]
```

I already tried the following code but it was not successful:

```
result=[([any(i == big_array ) for i in small_array])]
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```py
sum([row in small_array for row in big_array])
```

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
big_array = np.array([[1., 2., 1.2], [5., 3., 0.12], [-1., 14., 0.], [-9., 0., 13.]])
small_array= np.array([[5., 3., 0.12], [-1., 14., 0.]])

result = sum([row in small_array for row in big_array])
print(result)
```

> 2

---

Edit (after clarifications):

A pythonic solution:

```py
[i for i, brow in enumerate(big_array) for srow in small_array if all(srow == brow)]
```

Example:

```py
big_array = np.array([[1., 2., 1.2], [5., 3., 0.12], [-1., 14., 0.], [-9., 0., 13.]])
small_array= np.array([[5., 3., 0.12], [-1., 14., 0.]])

result = [i for i, brow in enumerate(big_array) for srow in small_array if all(srow == brow)]

print(result)
```

> [1, 2]

*Note*: you could probably do something better with `np.where`, if you have huge arrays you should look it up

Comment: Dear @Djib2011, Thanks for your help. Your solution is giving me the total number of rows which are the same, but I want to find the indices of this rows in the `big_array`. I want to do somthing like `np.in1d` for 2d arrays.

Comment: @Ali_d I misinterpreted your original question. Now after clarifications, I updated my answer.