# How to get a 2D array containing indices of another 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

#### Problem

```
import numpy as np
```

I have an an array, *without any prior information of its contents*. For example:

```
ourarray = \
np.array([[0,1],
          [2,3],
          [4,5]])
```

I want to get the pairs of numbers which can be used for indexing `ourarray`. Ie I want to get:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

(`0,0`, `0,1`, `1,0`, etc., all the possible indices of `ourarray` are in this array.)

---

#### Similar but different posts

- [how to find indices of a 2d numpy array occuring in another 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001287/how-to-find-indices-of-a-2d-numpy-array-occuring-in-another-2d-array): here they search for one array within another one, not returning indices of the entire array.
- [Find indices of rows of numpy 2d array in another 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930665/find-indices-of-rows-of-numpy-2d-array-in-another-2d-array): they are dealing with two arrays to start with, the objective *isn't* to create a second array based on the first one containing its indices

---

#### Attempt 1 (Successful but inefficient)

I can get this array by:

```
np.array(np.where(np.ones(ourarray.shape)))
```

Which gives the desired result but it requires creting `np.ones(ourarray.shape)`, which seems like not an efficient way of doing it.

---

#### Attempt 2 (Failed)

I also tried:

```
np.array(np.where(ourarray))
```

which does not work because there is no indices returned for the `0` entry of `ourarray`.

---

#### Question

**Attempt 1 works, but I am looking for a more efficient way. How can I do this more efficiently?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you intend to use this index?

The tuple produced by `nonzero` (`where`) is designed for convenient indexing:

```
In [54]: idx = np.nonzero(np.ones_like(ourarray))
In [55]: idx
Out[55]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]))
In [56]: ourarray[idx]
Out[56]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

or equivalently using the 2 arrays explicitly:

```
In [57]: ourarray[idx[0], idx[1]]
Out[57]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Your `np.array(idx)` can be used as in [57] but not as in [56].  The use of a `tuple` in [56] is important.

If we apply `transpose` to this we get an array.

```
In [58]: tidx = np.transpose(idx)
In [59]: tidx
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1]])
```

to use that for indexing we have to iterate:

```
In [60]: [ourarray[i,j] for i,j in tidx]
Out[60]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`argwhere` as proposed in the other answer is just the transpose.  Using `outarray>=0` is really no different from the `np.ones` expression.  Both make an array that is `True/1` for all elements.

```
In [61]: np.argwhere(np.ones_like(ourarray))
Out[61]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1]])
```

There are other ways of generating indices, `np.indices`, `np.meshgrid` , `np.mgrid`, `np.ndindex`, but they will require some sort of reshaping and/or transpose to get exactly what you want:

```
In [71]: np.indices(ourarray.shape)
Out[71]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
In [72]: np.indices(ourarray.shape).reshape(2,6)
Out[72]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

### timings

If `ourarray>=0` works, it is faster than `np.ones`:

```
In [79]: timeit np.ones_like(ourarray)
6.22 µs ± 11.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [80]: timeit ourarray>=0
1.43 µs ± 15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

`np.where/nonzero` adds a non-trivial time to that:

```
In [81]: timeit np.nonzero(ourarray>=0)
6.43 µs ± 8.15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and a bit more time to convert the tuple to array:

```
In [82]: timeit np.array(np.nonzero(ourarray>=0))
10.4 µs ± 35.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `transpose` round trip of `argwhere` adds more time:

```
In [83]: timeit np.argwhere(ourarray>=0).T
16.9 µs ± 35.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`indices` is about the same as [82], though it may scale differently.

```
In [84]: timeit np.indices(ourarray.shape).reshape(2,-1)
10.9 µs ± 33.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) then use `.T` and get what you want.

try this:

```
>>> ourarray = np.array([[0,1],[2,3], [4,5]])
>>> np.argwhere(ourarray>=0).T
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

If maybe any values exist in your array you can use this:

```
ourarray = np.array([[np.nan,1],[2,np.inf], [-4,-5]])
np.argwhere(np.ones(ourarray.shape)==1).T
# array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you. What would you use if I don't know anything about the array (I don't), so if some values could be negative?

Comment: Or not even negative, but NaN, for example, anything.

Comment: Thank you, awesome! I'll leave the question open for a wile in case someone has a solution without creating an array with np.ones (like this post does or my question, see Attempt 1). But in any case, definitely worth my +1, and if there won't be any more attractive solution, I'll accept this anwer.

Comment: `argwhere` is `transpose(where(...))`, turning the tuple into an array.  This doesn't address the OP's efficiency worry, since you still create the full `ones` or equivalent.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for your comment, I'm here for learning, I definitely approve your comment if you help me I can find a better approach or send your answer.